# How can I find very similar but NOT equal rows within two pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two columns from two different `dataframes` to get similar values. The values are strings, so they are not just the same, but very similar. How can I get those similar values?

The dataframes that I use are like the following:

```
Dataframe 1, column "Company", row = "Company_name"

Dataframe 2, column "Company", row = "Company_name_INC"
```

What I would like to get:

```
Dataframe 3, column "Company_source_1" row = "Company_name", column "Company_source_2", row = "Company_name_INC"
```

I need to find those names that are almost the same, in order to find the companies that appear in both dataframes.

Comment: Please tell what you have tried so far, and what do you mean by similar?

Comment: Similar as "Company_name" with "Company_name_INC"

Comment: So all the company names just have a "_INC" concatenated?

Comment: Please read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @TusharAggarwal No, it is just an example, it could include different things "SL" or anything else.

Comment: Please edit your question and include a few examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

Regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) can be used to do exactly what you are asking. For example, if you are looking for a company related to 'Regex' such as:

```
Regex
Regex_inc
NotRegex
```

You can do the following:

[Note that I have converted the DataFrame column `Name` to a Series and use the `.str.contains()` method, which can be used to index the appropriate rows from your original DataFrame (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html )]

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Regex', 'company_1'],
    ['Regex_inc', 'company_2'],
    ['NotRegex', 'company_3']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={0:'Name', 1:'Company'})
df_sorted = df[pd.Series(df['Name']).str.contains(r'^Regex')]
print df
print df_sorted
```

Returns

```
        Name    Company
0      Regex  company_1
1  Regex_inc  company_2
2   NotRegex  company_3
```

for `df`, and:

```
       Name    Company
0      Regex  company_1
1  Regex_inc  company_2
```

for `df_sorted`

The argument for the `pd.Series.str.contains()` method was `'^Regex'` which states that for a string to return a `True` value, it must begin with `'Regex'`.

I used this regex cheatsheet (https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) for the special characters. I'm not an expert on Regex, but plenty of material can be found online, also with the links contained in this answer. Also here (https://regex101.com/) is a regex tester than can be used to test your patterns.